# linear-layout background in API 19

Tags: android, eclipse, background, android-linearlayout

In API 19 (4.4.2) I'm trying to set solid color to my linear-layout background but that color cover my views like buttons backgrounds. I try to change buttons background separately but they lose their format and shading. What can I do to set linear-layout background without effects other views BG?

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00f"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Status_Update"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Update_Button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/EditText_Hint"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

I cant insert difference between two previews with same code because of my less reputation.
when i change my graphical layout preview to level 10 all things looks good but problem is when i change it to newer preview and run on 4.4.2 emulator.
I test it on a physical device and result is the same as emulator.

Comment: show your layouts(xml)

Comment: `In API 19 (4.2.2)` - `4.2.2` is API Level **17**, not 19. Did you mean `4.4.2`?

Comment: sorry, you are right, my problem is in 4.4.2(API 19),
here is my layout XML: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3776/ybthg5sv_jpg.htm
when i change my graphical layout preview to level 10 all things looks great but problem is when i change it to newer preview and run on 4.4.2 emulator.

Comment: Please add your **code** to your question, instead of linking an image. Anyway, by looking at that screenshot, it seems that the problem is the emulator, misworking (it's not so infrequent). Test your app on a physical device.

Comment: OK, sorry i'm new here. i cant add image here because of my less reputation. thanks for your opinion, I test it on a physical device and result is the same as emulator.